# Drop-down menu using CSS

Tags: css

I am a newbie in web programming! I have been working on a drop down menu and this is what I have got:

HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Drop Down Menu</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Drop Down Menu</h1>
<hr>
<div>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Categories</a>
      <ul id="sub">
         <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Web</a></li>
          <ul id="sub2">
            <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
          </ul>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Popular</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</body>
</html>`
```

CSS Code

```
#nav{
    list-style:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    z-index:5;
}
#nav li{
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    position:relative;
}
#nav a{
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav a:hover{
    color:#fff;
    background:#6b0c36;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
#nav #sub{
    background:#fff; 
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0); 
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px; 
}
#nav #sub li{
    padding-top:1px;
    float:none;
}
#nav #sub a{
    white-space:nowrap; 
}
#nav li:hover #sub{ 
    left:0; 
}

#nav li:hover #sub #sub2 {
    background:#fff;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0);
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    display: none;
}

#nav #sub li:hover #sub2{
    display:block;
}

#nav li:hover a{ 
    background:#6b0c36;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
#nav li:hover #sub a{ 
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav li:hover #sub li a:hover{ 
    background:#333;
}
```

My  problem is that on hovering on Web sub-block, the HTML and CSS UL doesn't show. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `#nav #sub li:hover #sub2 {display:block}`

`#nav li:hover #sub #sub2 {display:block}`

I am guessing your rules are not applied correctly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/d9UDT/

part of updated HTML

```
<li><a href="#">Web</a>
            <ul id="sub2" class="submenu">
              <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
```

part of updated CSS

```
#nav ul.submenu{
    background:#fff; 
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0); 
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px; 
}


#nav li:hover > ul.submenu{ 
    left:0; 
}
```

1) it seems that your markup is bit wrong

```
<li><a href="#">Web</a></li>
          <ul id="sub2">
            <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
          </ul>
```

this should be this

```
<li><a href="#">Web</a>
            <ul id="sub2" class="submenu">
              <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
```

2) instead of adding styles to id you can add them to class so that same class you can use on other drop down list as well

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect HTML structure you need to add

```
<ul id="sub2">
            <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
          </ul>
```

In side `<li>`

[Here is demo for it](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hCbHr/)